# Returning Specific JSON Data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm an oldschooler coming from MySQL, and some work I've started doing is now in JSON, which is a new world to me, so bear with me if this seems obvious, but I'm having a very hard time finding help on Google for this--

**I've retrieved the JSON data in a table, which was my first step, but what I want to do now is return JUST one entry based on a reference.  For example, if I was to use the value "29974" as the ID, I'd want to see the name, description, and image related to that ID.**

What I'm using now, which successfully returns all data into a table:

```html
<table id='table'> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Item ID</th> 
        <th>Item Name</th> 
        <th>Description</th> 
        <th>Item Image</th> 
    </tr> 
  
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $.getJSON("ravendata.json",  
                    function (data) { 
                var itemlist = ''; 

                $.each(data, function (key, value) { 
                    itemlist += '<tr>'; 
                    itemlist += '<td>' +  
                        value.id + '</td>'; 
                    itemlist += '<td>' +  
                        value.name + '</td>'; 
                    itemlist += '<td>' +  
                        value.description + '</td>'; 
                    itemlist += '<td>' +  
                        value.image + '</td>'; 
                    itemlist += '</tr>'; 
                }); 

                $('#table').append(itemlist); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Some of the JSON string:

```json
  {
    "id": 29974,
    "name": "Infusion",
    "description": "Used for infusions.",
    "image": "IMAGEINFUSION"
  },
  {
    "id": 31857,
    "name": "wool",
    "description": "Used in various recipes. A staple crafting material since the dawn of civilization.",
    "image": "IMAGEWOOL"
  }
```